# Gulp/Grunt: Concatenate only necessary JS files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build-process, gulp, gulp-concat

### Wot I got

I have a gulpfile that produces `app.min.js` and `libs.min.js`; fairly selfexplanatory:

```
var dev = {
    libs: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls.min.js',
        'bower_components/underscore.string/dist/underscore.string.min.js'
    ]
};

var build = {
    js: 'public/js'
};

gulp.task('libs', function() {
    return gulp.src(dev.libs)
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build.js));
});
```

In this setup, whenever I add or remove a library, I have to manually add it to the `dev.libs` array (and in the right order, too), then restart Gulp to see the new lib file.

### Wot I WANT

I want to be able to concat the js libs I use *without having to specifically define them* in `(array) dev.libs`. At the moment if I use `return gulp.src('**/*.js')`, I believe it will concat every single js file in `bower_components`, which'd obviously be ridiculous.

### Question

**Is there a way to *automatically load* and *concat* the libraries I need, without having to define them in a gulpfile?**

Comment: You should be using a module system such as CommonJS and a bundler like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) for this. Your life will get much, much easier

Comment: @Bojangles - Any reason to use CommonJS over RequireJS? I've just had a quick gander at both, and the latter sounds more useful for client-side use.

Comment: RequireJS can load modules asynchronously, but I personally strongly dislike the double definitions at the top of files and the fact you need to wrap everything in a callback for each module.  Choose one you like that firs your needs and try it out. Both systems have well established ecosystems. CommonJS (Browserify) is used by Node however, so creating isomorphic apps is much easier with Browserify

Comment: I've done some further reading, and I'm sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *Bower*, you can use the plugin **[main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files)** that will parse the content of your `bower.json` and search for the `main` file(s) of each of your dependency, so you don't have to declare each lib.

```
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
```

You can then do :

```
gulp.task('libs', function () {
  return gulp.src(bowerFiles())
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build.js));
});
```

Comment: I'm torn between using this for it's Bower support, and Browserify and it's added dependency management. Nevertheless, this exactly solves my stated issue, so thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :) I personally prefer to use *Bower* coupled with *Npm*, but it's up to you